# checking normality of residuals

Tags: r, glm

I am to test the normality of a set of residuals in a model

```r
glm(Failure ~ Lead ,data=Exercise2, family="binomial")
summary(glm(Failure ~ Lead ,data=Exercise2, family="binomial"))

hist(summary(glm(Failure ~ Lead ,data=Exercise2, family="binomial"))$resi)
```

I have added the is.numeric to confirm my data is numeric

```r
is.numeric(Exercise2$Lead)
is.numeric(Exercise2$Failure)
```

The output i am getting is below

> Error in hist.default(summary(glm(Failure ~ Lead, data = Exercise2, family = "binomial"))$resi) :
> 'x' must be numeric

```r
> is.numeric(Exercise2$Lead)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(Exercise2$Failure)
[1] TRUE
```

Can anyone advise why i am getting an error that data must be numeric when the data is numeric ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```r
m1 <- glm(Failure ~ Lead ,data=Exercise2, family="binomial")
hist(residuals(m1, type = "pearson"))
```

Or `plot(m1, which = 2)` to get a Q-Q plot (which is a better way to judge normality of residuals)

Your problem is that the result of `glm(...)` is not a numeric vector - it is a complicated object of class `glm` (try `str(m1)`)

Comment: A typo there. It should be- 
`hist(residuals(m1, type = "pearson"))`

Answer (score 0):

Shapiro-Wilk Test

```
shapiro.test(residual)
```

Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

```
ks.test(residual, 'pnorm')
```

---

```
mod.2    <- glm(Failure ~ Lead ,data=Exercise2, family="binomial")
residual <- resid(mod.2,type="working")
```

Comment: The use of p-value based tests to check normality of residuals is no longer recommended for several reasons. (1) the tests are not powerful enough for small samples when normality might be important, (2) they are too powerful for large samples, when normality is less imprtant due to the central limit theorem, (3) the KS-test is not adequately used in the example above, (4) pre-tests are conceptually questionable anyway. Therefore: think  whether normality could at all be possiblea by the way your data are generated, and **use graphical methods** as recommended by @Ben Bolker.

Comment: Totally agree with tpetzoldt.  My understanding it that they can be used in an automated fashion (which is difficult for graphical methods), but only if you understand their limitations in your circumstance and only to test for "outrageousness"